# Calculate $\int \frac{1}{x^2+x+1}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

Define the integral $I$ as follow:

$$I=\int \dfrac{1}{x^2+x+1}\mathrm{d}x.$$

I do not know how to integrate it. Any suggestions please?

I tried a lot of methods:

- I substituted $x^2+x=u$.
- I modified the denominator $x^2+x+1=(x+1)^2-x$ and I substituted $x+1=u$.

I know that it is somewhat very easy to do it but I am stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: Try going via $x^2+x+1=(x+\frac 12)^2+\frac 34$ and put the integrand in the standard form $\frac 1{y^2+a^2}$

Comment: Remember that there is a standard technique in algebra for reducing a problem involving a quadratic polynomial with a first-degree term to a problem involving a quadratic polynomial with no first-degree term.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint**

Complete the square $x^2+x+1=\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34$
and change the variable to use 
$$\int\frac{du}{u^2+1}=\arctan u+C$$

Comment: lol ... you write hint and give almost full answer. Cheers!!

Comment: I didn't give explicitly the change of variable;-)

Comment: Hope this gets to "nice answer"!

Answer (score 5):

$(x+1/2)^2+3/4$  substitute $u=x+1/2$

Answer (score 3):

complete the square as $x^2 + x + 1 = \left( x + \frac 1 2\right)^2 + \frac 3 4$, then use the substitution $\left( x + \frac 1 2\right) = u $ you will get 
$$\int \frac{1}{u^2 + \left(\frac {\sqrt 3 }{2}\right )^2}du$$
which I believe has got something to do with $\arctan(u)$

Comment: $(x+1/2)=u$ will not give the next integrand? I am afraid.

Comment: @MarkBennet thanks corrected. is should have been careful.